# Problems using Document.parse over Aggregation static methods in mongo aggregation in spring data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

When using aggregation pipeline with mongo in spring-data, we often face complex pipelines. In these scenarios, the [Aggregation class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html) provided by spring-data doesn't cover all the possible queries. Granted it covers more queries/functionalities now than when I started using over two~three years ago.

Example of a Document.parse vs Aggregation

```java
Aggregation.newAggregation(
 // Document.parse here
 aggregationOperationContext -> Document.parse("{ $match: { 'field': " + value + " } }"), 
 // Aggregation here
 Aggregation.match(field, value)
);
```

These are the list that I came up with about benefits of each method:

Benefits of using Document.parse():

- What you write in the query to be parsed, it's what the java driver will utilize. There is less middle-man here.
- Allow complex queries (could be good and bad. I've seen people making complex queries while a simple query would've achieved the same result)

Benefits of using Aggregation provided by spring-data

- Succinct syntax
- Less likely to errors from typos

My point for posting here is that often time, my team and I discuss if there is any real advantage of using the Aggregation class over tossing the Document.parse() with what we need. Is there other things that I didn't list above? Like, performance, easy of testing, etc? I couldn't see in their source code anything obvious to me. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `MongoRepository`'s `@Aggregation` annotation to specify the pipelines. What is the reason you are trying to use the`Document.parse`? Is there a specific query or scenario you have trouble with?

Comment: Yes, a couple scenarios. I know most "recently" they added more capabilities (ex: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/789), but still project existed before that and we still have edge cases

Comment: I think, you can post individual / specific issues (with details) you are facing and someone can see and try to reply / answer. Also, you can run MongoDB Aggregation _native_ queries using the `MongoTemplate`. Thats a lot of options and flexibility. So, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Your suggestion is valid about the specific issues/queries, but I'm curious to know what are the problems of using Document.parse over the Aggregation that spring-data offers.